# Google map sync geocode delay

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Here is it, [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rMxNL/)

As you can see, I intend to make separate functions for google map features. The `locate_self()` function is used to return latlng coordinates of current geolocation while the `initialize_map()` function draws the map and accept optional predefined coordinated otherwise, use a default random coordinates.

The problem is, `initialize_map()` fired faster than `locate_self()`, rendering the returned element as `undefined` and finally, `initialize_map()` goes with default coordinate.

Inside `locate_self()`, I created a test block by giving an `alert()`, along with current geolocation coordinates to indicates that this function is working properly.

The question is how do I make `initialize_map()` **wait** for locate_self() until it **returns the coordinate** rather than `undefined` ?

I will use the same solution later for function that accept latlng and return address string. Geocoder also have the same kind of 'delay'.

I tried using timeout before but it still giving me undefined (maybe I was wrong placing the timeout block, I don't know).

Thanks and I'm very sorry if this is a repost

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The geolocation service is asynchronous. The simplest way around this is to use a callback instead of using `return`:

```
function initialize_map(result) {
  if (result !== 'error') {
    gm_map = new google.maps.Map(gm_map_container, gm_map_options);
    if (!result) {
      result = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
    }
    gm_map.setCenter(result);
  }
}

function locate_self(callback) {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
      var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
      callback(pos);
    });
  } else { callback('error'); }
}

locate_self(initialize_map);
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/j8uCA/4/).

Comment: While this works, I don't think this is a good approach. If a user doesn't allow geolocation, he gets no map at all.

Comment: Fair point, but that wasn't the question. The question was "how do I make initialize_map() wait for locate_self() until it returns the coordinate".

Comment: Thanks guys, I really appreciate the help. Andy's answer is the closest to what I expecting. While it has thing to consider as MrUpsidown mentioned, I'll just need to find another way. It looks like the root of the problem is "how to get return from async functions". Time to do some learning.

Comment: @Andy You are right! I think your answer is closer to the question and mine is maybe closer to *usual behavior*.

Answer (score 2):

Why not do it the other way around?

1. Display the map
2. Geolocate user and set center

http://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/rMxNL/2/

```
var gm_map_container = document.getElementById('container');
var gm_map_options = { zoom: 8 };

function initialize_map(location) {
    gm_map = new google.maps.Map(gm_map_container,gm_map_options);
    if (!location) { location = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644); }
    gm_map.setCenter(location);

    locate_self();
}

function locate_self() {
    if(navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {

            var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
            gm_map.setCenter(pos);
        });
    } else { return false; }
}

initialize_map();
```